# Receiving Document Content in Base64 Encoder format in Postman

Tags: java, postman, microservices

I'm hitting URL in Postman to download the document but receiving docContent in Base64 Encoder format.

I'm using JAVA EE framework for microservices

URL: https://testURL.com/getDocument

Content-Type: application/xml

JVBTEKJhekjdjhjkegje....

How can I decode in Postman and download the document in local?

Comment: What is your actual problem: that you cannot serve a proper answer (content type doesn't match the actual content), that you do not evaluate all headers (maybe this is a compressed answer, but you do not show all headers) or that you get Postman to handle the incorrect answer in a way you would prefer?

Comment: When I testing the API to download the document, I'm receiving 200 response and the required Data. But the problem is the document data receiving in Base64 encoder format like <fileName>"my-file.pdf"</fileName>
    <docContent>JVBERi0xLjcKJeLjz9MNCj...</docContent> . I need to save  or view the document. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: So your problem is that the endpoint you call does encode the body in bas64 which is completely unnecessary since XML is a pure text format and there is no need to encode it in base64. Do you have any control over the endpoint? HTTP could transfer binary data directly and base64 endcoding is usually used for mail attachments, not for HTTP requests.

Comment: No, I don't have control. I'm just consuming the API which the other team provided us.

Comment: so effectively you should report a but against that API as the Content-Type header does not match the content.
In Postman you probably don't have a chance other than to save the answer into a file (or copy it to the clipboard) and use another external tool (`base64` in Linux e.g. or an online tool) to decode the answer. In software you will have to treat that kind of API very special (=> send a request "manually" and handle the answer "manually"), I doubt that you will find a framework that can handle this broken state automatically.